# What is the difference between null, 0 and nothing?

Tags: java, null, zero

What is the difference between `null`, `0` and `nothing`?

I cannot find a question addressing all three of these.

For example:

If I am getting input from a `string` and parsing it to `int`.

```
return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

Or if I am asking if a `string != ""`, or a `is not nothing` I am confused about which to use when and why.

I am confused about which one to use when validating data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`null` means that a variable contains a reference to a space in memory that does not contain an object.

`0` is a numeric data type with a value of 0.

`Nothing` doesn't really exist, however I think you may be viewing this as an empty String `""` which is simply a `String` data type that does not contain a value.

If your looking at this from a `Javascript` paradigm it may be confusing.  In Java variables are not truthy and falsey therefore the type is considered in comparisons.

Comment: In Java `void` just indicates that a method does not return an object or primitive.

Comment: is null equals with NULL?

Answer (score 9):

0 is a number, you use it to check if a numeric value (int, short, float, double, etc.) is the number 0.

`null` is the value of a reference that points nowhere, you use it to make sure a reference does indeed reference something.

`nothing` is not part of Java.

The closest thing for nothing (for: no information at all) is the `void` declaration of a method. It states that the method returns literally nothing.

Note that 0, `null` and the empty string `""` are values and thus contain information.

For example, 0 is the answer to "What is 5 subtracted from 5?" (among others).

`null` is the negative response to "Does this thing point to an object?".

`""`" could be the answer to "What is the longest sequenc of 'X's in your name?", unless your name is "Xanthippe".

Comment: Yes, it declares that a method (and only methods can be void) is not going to return anything. But you can't check if some value is void, hence it is in a different category with 0 and `null`, which are values.

Comment: Updated my answer to include `void`.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a "nothing" in Java. There is a `null` reference, meaning that a variable refers to no object, so it is a kind of nothing, but there isn't the concept of `undefined` as it is in Javascript.

Also, please note that a `String` comparison should be done using `equals`, not `!=` or `==`, so `string.equals(otherString)`.

The `0` value is the default value that an `int` gets when declared as an instance variable.

Comment: @Skippy `undefined` (in JS) is as much of a something (or "nothing") as `null` is. It is a sentinel value. Now, `void` in Java represents nothing .. and their is no value which can satisfy it.

Comment: "The 0 value is the default value that an int gets when declared." No, no, no!

Comment: @Ingo Why not? int x; What is the value of x if you print it?

Comment: In a method? Try it, Dan.

Comment: I didn't say anything about a method, but I added something to make sure it is not interpreted.

Comment: You did say "when declared". In a method, `int x;` is a declaration of an int, is it not?

Answer (score 5):

`"Null"` in Java , the object reference is not pointing to any object, it is null.

`"Nothing"`, Java has nothing called "Nothing"

`"0"` means that .the string object exists with a value of "0"

`""` means an empty String ,i.e the String Object exists with value ""

Answer (score 5):

- "nothing" means nothing in Java.
- 0 means an integer value greater than -1 and less than 1.
- "Null" means if any Object Reference points nowhere in the memory, then it's called "Null" reference.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach to check String objects in Java is using org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.

If you do not want to use `StringUtils`, you might want to check that `sc.nextList()` is not null (`!= null`) first of all, if it is not null then you can check that is different from "" (`!= ""`).

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
int s;      //s=null
int s = 0 ;  //s=0
String s="";// s=nothing
```

Comment: int cannot be NULL!!! NEVER NEVER NEVER! NULL is an object value which reference that the object does not have an memory allocation! (This post tagged with java)

Comment: The empty string is not nothing. It is a perfect valid string value, which plays a role very similar to 0 in the realm of natural numbers. For example, both "" and 0 are neutral elements for some operation (both named +).

Answer (score 2):

Null variable isn't assigned any value. The memory space (of variable) is empty or holds garbage value.
while a variable is 0, the variable holds the value '0'. The memory space has value '0' stored in it.

NULL  basically means no value, or unknown,NULL value could be either empty, meaningless, or not even initialized. For eg when we say, Employee bonus is null, it means the person is not getting any bonus or not eligible for bonus.now in case if value is 0 its mean employee getting bonus but currently bonus is zero.