# Method Overloading for Null Argument by passing 0 and null

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, overloading

I have seen questions on Stack Overflow about a method overloading for null argument but didn't solve my confusion and I tried something different which was not discussed in there answers that's why asking this question.

I want the reason when I pass "null" it executes the function whose argument type is double and when I pass "0" or any other numeric digit like 1,2,10 etc to the function it executes the function whose argument type is "Object". I know there is a difference in NULL and 0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653937/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-nothing) is the difference.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
public class NullArgumentOverloading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NullArgumentOverloading obj = new NullArgumentOverloading();
        obj.overLoad(null); // prints "Double array argument method."
        obj.overLoad(0); // prints "Object o argument method."
    }

    private void overLoad(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object o argument method.");
    }

    private void overLoad(double[] dArray) {
        System.out.println("Double array argument method.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `0` gets autoboxed into `Integer` which is not a `double[]` but an `Object`.

Comment: ok fine but why double argument get execute when we pass null to the function.

Comment: Because it uses the most specific method possible, and `double[]` is more specific than `Object`.

Comment: hmmm, Thanks!!!

Comment: @daniu correct me if I am wrong when I pass 0 the wrapper class converts it into Integer which is a subclass of Object that's why it executes Object argument and when I pass "null" in the arguments it is more specific to an array because it referring to some memory slot which is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java will always try to use the most specific version of a method that's available (see JLS [15.12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)).

`Object`, `double[]` can both take null as a valid value. Therefore both are suitable.

`Object` is the super-type of `double[]` and therefore more specific than just `Object`. So thats the reason why it prints "Double array argument method." when you pass `null` to the function

For the ohter Question: 
As already explained in the comments, when you pass `0` which is a primitive `int`, will be boxed automatically into an `Integer` which have `Object` as super-type, so it prints "Object o argument method."

You can find more info in [Method Overloading for null argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-argument)

Comment: Thank you for your clarification,